# Are there sites for discussing more informally about computational modelling?

Tags: education

Are there sites for discussing more informally about computational modelling?

Forum-style, rather than QA.

Comment: Sound like that would be an excellent slack channel https://slack.com

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of resources I know worth trying; however, in my opinion, they either lack the focus or do not have the required audience.

1. One of the subreddits: [/r/CompSci](https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/). Though it is mainly used for computer science and applications, it should be appropriate for discussion on computational science topics. It is pretty popular (234K subscribers), but I doubt it is easy to find the right crowd there.
2. Other thematic subreddits ([/r/Chemistry](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/), [/r/Science](https://www.reddit.com/r/science/), [/r/Math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/), [/r/Physics](https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/), [/r/MachineLearning](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/)) might be also appropriate for particular discussions devoted to computational modeling topics. There are also smaller communities there, some of them more active than the others.
3. Although I am not aware of a particular Facebook group for computational modeling/science, one can find reasonable communities on Facebook. (For example, [Facebook: Data Science](https://www.facebook.com/search/str/data+science/keywords_groups)).
4. One can also find relevant groups on LinkedIn. ([High-Performance & Supercomputing](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/95317), [HPC](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/87791), [Computational electromagnetics](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2126533))
5. Some activity in forum-like discussions on relevant topics can be found on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/home.Home.html).

There is also a classic example of a science-focused forum in Russian that is still very alive:

6. [DxDy](https://dxdy.ru/).

Generally, the era of social media and SE "killed" a lot of forums. So, the activity on typical forums right now is very limited.

I think there are good reasons, why forum-like discussions for certain areas are not too common nowadays. Forums (IMHO) tend to lose a discussion topic, become a place for flamewars and are generally counterproductive. That, in a way, gave rise to SE with stricter QA-rules.

Answer (score 2):

The Julia community has a lot of people who are focused on different aspects of scientific computing. Most of its [Discourse Forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/) is discussions of numerical issues, performance, simulation methods, and scientific computing packages. There's a lot of [other associated channels](https://julialang.org/community/) like the JuliaLang slack ([here for an invite](https://slackinvite.julialang.org/)). The differential equations channel from there is bridged to the [DiffEq Gitter](https://gitter.im/JuliaDiffEq/Lobby) with daily discussions on all things differential equations related. There's lot of Slack channels which are highly active like `#gpu`, `#machine-learning`, `#parallel`, `#linalg`, etc. where people are discussing algorithms and their implementations. The Julialang/julia Github is very lively as well, though more purpose-driven and requires a bit more prerequisite knowledge to join in. Altogether, it's a great community to discuss with if you're interested in all things scientific computing related.